# Error when using .FormulaR1C1 with an integer

Tags: excel, vba

Can anyone understand why does the following line of code return an error?

```
Dim nProd as integer

nProd = 4

Cells(2, 6 + nProd).FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(LEN(RC[-" & nProd & "])>0;RC[-" & nProd & "];"")"
```

(...)

It returns a run-time error '1004' on that last line of code and I cant figure out why...

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Use commas instead of semicolons.

Comment: ^^ That, and use `""""` as the last parameter or else the error will still remain.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! It was such a simple fix but I was freaking out for so long...